# jQuery Validate and disabled input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using below bootstrap as a dropdown picker, which then with an associated jQuery function displays the choosen field in the `input` `type="text"`. But users can still write their own in the input field, which I would like to avoid. I tried using the `disabled` attribute on the input field, but if I do that the jQuery Validate plugin will just ignore it and grant permission even if it's empty.

Is it possible to "deactivate" an input field with `type="text"`, without using the `disabled` attribute so that I may still use jQuery Validate.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Choose<span class="caret"></span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" id="a">1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="b">2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="c">3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="d">4</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="e">5</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
         <input type="text" id="abc" autocomplete="off" name="abc" placeholder="Select *" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: So where is the relevant JavaScript?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no direct solution... if the field is "disabled" via the `disabled` attribute, the jQuery Validate plugin will always ignore it.  (Logically, there is no point in validating something the user cannot edit.)

However there is a workaround.  If you use the `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`, it can be validated.

```
<input type="text" name="abc" readonly="readonly" />
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/85pu1oe5/**

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to use the `readonly="readonly"` attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Answer (score 0):

No matter how od this question is - there is a workaround which is quite simple. Why not using a hidden field additionally to the one disabled that is ignored by jquery.validate.js?

e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['name']); ?>" disabled>
<input type="hidden" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo htmlentities($user['name']); ?>">
```

Works well for me. Same goes for

```
<select style="display:none;"><option value="sample">Sample</option></select>
```

display: none; will hide the element, completely (space and all). It is still enabled and thus its data still sent. Have a try.

Make sure, ignore: ".ignore", is added to the validate.js because it enables all hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to rely on `validator.showErrors()` method and manually validate this disabled input.

I had a similar situation when I needed to validate terms checkbox, but it was designed to be disabled until user scrolls through the terms text.
That's what I come up with in the end:

```
        var message = "You must accept the Terms and Conditions in order to proceed with registration";
        var termsValidator = $('#step-5 form').validate({
            rules: {
                acceptTnC: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                acceptTnC: message
            },
            submitHandler : function (form) {
                // Need to manually validate, cause checkbox is disabled by default and validation
                // skips disabled fields
                if(!form.acceptTnC.checked) {
                    termsValidator.showErrors({
                        acceptTnC: message
                    })
                }
                else {
                    submitForm();
                }
            }
        });
        $('[name="acceptTnC"]').on('change', function (e) {
            termsValidator.element(e.target);
        })
```

Bottom part is important to toggle error message once the checkbox is enabled and user can click it on or off